# Find number of reserved machines so that cost be minimum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, binomial-distribution, operations-research

> In a company we have $20$ similar machines . Number of damaged machines has binomial distribution with $p = 0.3$. In other words, $$\mathbb{P}[X = k] = { 20 \choose k}0.3^k 0.7^{20-k}.$$ In order to repairing damaged machines , we should pay $150$  for each of them . The company is able to buy new machines and replace with the damaged machines but the cost for maintaining of reserved machines is $200$  for each . Find number of reserved machines that company should buy so that the cost be minimum .

**My try** : Let $k$ be number of damaged machines , $k'$ reserved machines and $C$ cost . This algorithm finds the cost :

if $k \gt k'$  $$C = 50k + 150(k - k')$$
if $k = k'$  $$C = 50k$$
if $k \lt k'$  $$C = 50k + 200(k' - k)$$

And I got stuck here , thanks in advance !

Comment: The cost is stochastic, so you should define what cost you are interested in. Expected cost?

Comment: @LinAlg I'm interested in the sum of money needs for repairing machines and buying reserved machines .

Comment: Cost to buy a machine occurs at an instant while maintenance cost is accrued over a period. To relate the two it is necessary to know the maintenance cost *per what period* and the lifespan of a machine. Then are you looking to minimise cost in the first year or the long term over the lives of the machines?